# Flutter mantener datos aún después de actualizar la app

Tags: flutter, app, local-storage

Estoy usando flutter y guardando datos en un archivo local json.
El problema que tengo es que cada vez que lanzo actualización a play store, cuando el usuario actualiza pierde dicha información.

Como puedo hacer para que los datos persistan después de actualización.
Ahora estoy usando el paquete

```
    import dart:io
    Future<void> putSearchHistory(
{

    required TypeEquipo tipo,
     required List<SearchHistoryItem> equipos}) async { 
    
        try { String 

pathFileName = 
    await getLocalPathFileName(fileName: tipo.toString()); 
    dynamic jsonEquiposEncoded = jsonEncode(equipos);
     File file = File(pathFileName);
     await file.writeAsString(jsonEquiposEncoded; } catch (e) { 
    throw DbNotFound('Db not found $e'); } }
```

Comment: hmm agrega la info de como guardas el archivo local, que usas para eso? considera usar Shared Preferences

Comment: Hola uso el paquete buildin darte:lo
  Future<void> putSearchHistory( 
       {required TypeEquipo tipo, 
       required List<SearchHistoryItem> equipos}) async { 
     try { 
       String pathFileName = 
           await getLocalPathFileName(fileName: tipo.toString()); 
       dynamic jsonEquiposEncoded = jsonEncode(equipos); 
       File file = File(pathFileName); 
       await file.writeAsString(jsonEquiposEncoded); 
     } catch (e) { 
       throw DbNotFound('Db not found $e'); 
     } 
   }

Comment: eso añádelo a la pregunta, no como comentario, también agrega este método:  getLocalPathFileName

Comment: import 'dart:io';.                         
Uso ese paquete   Importo marcadores de archivos KML que pesan aprox 5mb cada uno. En ese caso es recomendable usar shared preferences?

Comment: no, en ese caso debes guardar los archivos pero en el almacenamiento externo, revisa si no estás usando el path temporal para guardar archivos

Comment: Future<String> get _localDirectoryPath async { 
   final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); 
   return directory.path; 
 } eso estoy usando.

Comment: Estoy haciendo bien y solo debo guardar en almacenamiento externo.

Comment: Ok. Como solución debo cambiar dirección a almacenamiento externo. Pero en otros casos si usaría sqllite tendria el mismo problema?

Comment: no deberías almacenar archivos pesados dentro de una BD, solo guardarlos en la carpeta de tu app para despues leerlos.

Comment: Es justo lo que hago con la función getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() en este caso tengo problema con las actualizaciones que lanzo en playstore. Ya leí tu recomendación de guardarlo en de externo. Eso es posible solo si el usuario cuenta con una. Que otra alternativa de solución puedes haber.? Gracias diegoveloper

Comment: probaste localmente? que sucede si instalas una versión con un version code superior, elimina el archivo? no debería pasar.

Comment: Hola Diegoveloper. Estuve pensando ayer todo el día en el problema. En la noche bien tarde me di cuenta, me acordé que cambie los nombres de los archivos después de una refactorización sería. En base a lo que me dices que no debería eliminar datos frente a una actualización, es obvio que el problema que tengo es el cambio de nombre de archivo. Soy nuevo en estoy mil disculpas es mi primera app en play store y gracias a eso y tu canal de Youtube estoy aprendiendo mucho.. saludos

Comment: Ah, era eso entonces, claro, si cambia el nombre entonces el usuario perderá el archivo en la actualización, mantén el mismo nombre siempre :)